# Editable div content

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I make a table containing some rules, i added a button so the user can edit any row onclicking on the edit button. i want to change the clicked row only not all rows. also i want to blur on the required row when the user click edit button.

```
const[isEditing, setIsEditing] = useState(false)
const onEditHandler = (event:any) =>{
        const editedRuleId = (event.target.id);
        
        setIsEditing(!isEditing);
    }

  <div className='container'>  
                {Object.entries(rules).map((rule) => (
                    <div key={rule[0]} className='tbl_rules'>
                        <div className='box-1'><h6>{rule[0]}</h6></div>
                        <div contentEditable={isEditing} className='box-2'>{rule[1]}</div>
                        <div className='box-3'>
                            <button 
                                id={rule[0]}
                                type="button" 
                                className="btn btn-sm btn-info"
                                onClick={onEditHandler}
                            >{isEditing ? 'Save' : 'Edit'}</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                ))}    
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way to do this would be to make each row a unique component.
So you would end up with code that looks like this:

```
<div className='container'>  
  {Object.entries(rules).map((rule) => (
     <Rule rule={rule}>
   ))}    
</div>
```

And in the `Rule` component, you would add the rest of your code  as follows which will allow each row to hold its own state:

```
const[isEditing, setIsEditing] = useState(false)
const onEditHandler = (event:any) => {
  const editedRuleId = (event.target.id);
  
  setIsEditing(!isEditing);
}

return (<div key={rule[0]} className='tbl_rules'>
  <div className='box-1'><h6>{rule[0]}</h6></div>
  <div contentEditable={isEditing} className='box-2'>{rule[1]}</div>
    <div className='box-3'>
      <button 
        id={rule[0]}
        type="button" 
        className="btn btn-sm btn-info"
        onClick={onEditHandler}
        >
      {isEditing ? 'Save' : 'Edit'}</button>
   </div>
  </div>);
```

Comment: i did that and got this warning: 
 react_devtools_backend.js:4061 Warning: A component is `contentEditable` and contains `children` managed by React.

Comment: Also i have error on the child component: export default function Rules({rules}) {...}. The error is: Binding element 'rules' implicitly has an 'any' type.

Comment: @NewReactDeveloper, I would need to see how you have implemented my answer into your codebase. I believe that you may not have set up or referenced the ```Rule``` component correctly and your type issue is unfortunately related to your linting rules which is outside the scope of your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
const [ selectedCell, setSelectedCell ] = useState(null) ;

<div className='container'>  
    {
        Object.entries(rules).map( ([rule, id]) => 
            return {
                <div key={id} className='tbl_rules'>
                    {
                        rule.map((item, index) => {
                            <div className='box-1'
                                contentEditable={selectedCell === id+"_"+index}
                                onClick={() => setSelectedCell(id+"_"+index)}
                            >
                                {item}
                            </div>
                        })
                    }
                </div>
            }
        )
    }    
</div> 

# for example rules
{
    row_1 : ["rule_1_1", "rule_1_2"],
    row_2 : ["rule_2_1", "rule_2_2"]
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).